# YoutubeSupportFragment loads after all other views in activity are loaded

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a fragment based activity in my application which reads data from an API using an Async task, data includes movie details along with some video ids. I have created another fragment which extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment and shows a thumbnail and allows to play the video. I am adding the youtube player based fragment in the main fragment using Supportfragmentmanager.

Everything works alright other than that youtube thumbnail inflates after every other view has inflated(e.g. text view, image view etc.) even though I am adding the youtube fragment before setting value for any other view in the content fragment. I have also tried making all the content invisible, load everything include youtube fragment and then setting visibility to true but even then youtube fragment loads about 2, 3 second after everything else has inflated already. Is there anyway to make youtube player fragment load faster?

This is content fragment layout.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context=".fragments.MovieDetailsFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_movie_details">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/movie_details_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <!-- Movie name, poster -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <!-- Youtube thumbnail-->
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnail_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    ></FrameLayout>
                <!-- Backdrop Image -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop_image_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail_layout"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/movie_details_backdrop_image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/backdrop_image_layout"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/movie_details_poster_thumb"
                        android:layout_width="75dp"
                        android:layout_height="110dp"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:elevation="10dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/movie_details_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/fontColorMaroon"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <!-- Movie rating, genre -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/borderset_topbottom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/movie_details_rating_image"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/rating" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/movie_details_rating"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                            android:text="9.3"
                            android:textColor="@color/iconColor"
                            android:textSize="13sp" />

                    </FrameLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/movie_details_votes"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="100"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/fontColorMaroon"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/smaller_font_size" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/voter" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/movie_details_genre_image"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/sport" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/movie_details_genre_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Film"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/fontColorMaroon"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/smaller_font_size" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Movie overview -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/movie_details_overview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@color/fontColorBlack"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/small_font_size" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/movie_details_progressbar_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <include layout="@layout/progressbar_item"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code for Async class which i am using is here ( i am calling my Async class from OnCreateView function of parent fragment above).

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Movie movie) {
    super.onPostExecute(movie);
    Utilities utilities = new Utilities(context);

    TextView itemRating = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.movie_details_rating);
    TextView itemVotes = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.movie_details_votes);
    TextView itemGenre = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.movie_details_genre_text);
    TextView itemOverview = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.movie_details_overview);
    TextView itemName = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.movie_details_name);

    ImageView itemGenreImage = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.movie_details_genre_image);
    ImageView itemBackdropImage  = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.movie_details_backdrop_image);
    ImageView itemPoster = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.movie_details_poster_thumb);

    FrameLayout thumbnailFrame = (FrameLayout)activity.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_layout);

    if(movie.isInternetAvailable()== true && movie != null){
        if(movie.getVideos().getVideos() != null && movie.getVideos().getVideos().size() != 0) {

            YoutubeThumbnailFragment youtubeThumbnailFragment = YoutubeThumbnailFragment.newInstance(movie.getVideos().getVideos().get(0).getKey());
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.thumbnail_layout,youtubeThumbnailFragment).commit();
            //thumbnailFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            String imageSize = utilities.GetBackdropSize();
            com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.with(context).load(context.getString(R.string.tmdb_image_url) + imageSize + movie.getBackdropPath()).into(itemBackdropImage);
            itemBackdropImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            thumbnailFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        itemName.setText(movie.getTitle());
        com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.with(context).load(context.getString(R.string.tmdb_image_url) + "w780" + movie.getPosterPath()).fit().into(itemPoster);

        itemRating.setText(String.format("%.1f", movie.getVoteAverage()));
        itemVotes.setText(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(movie.getVoteCount()));
        if(movie.getGenres() != null) {
            itemGenre.setText(movie.getGenres().get(0).getName());
            itemGenreImage.setImageResource(GetGenreImageResourceId(movie.getGenres().get(0).getId()));
        }
        itemOverview.setText(movie.getOverview());
        progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        contentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    else {
        progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        utilities.ShowInternetUnavailablityDialog(activity);
    }
}
```

And this is youtube fragement layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
            android:id="@+id/trailer_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/playImageView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/playbutton"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code for youtube fragment.

```
public class YoutubeThumbnailFragment extends Fragment implements YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener {
    private static final String KEY_VIDEO_ID = "video_id";
    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
    private String currentVideoID;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView;
    private YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader;


    public YoutubeThumbnailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static YoutubeThumbnailFragment newInstance(String videoId) {
        YoutubeThumbnailFragment fragment = new YoutubeThumbnailFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(KEY_VIDEO_ID, videoId);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Bundle arguments = getArguments();

        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_VIDEO_ID)) {
            currentVideoID = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_VIDEO_ID);
        } else if (arguments != null && arguments.containsKey(KEY_VIDEO_ID)) {
            currentVideoID = arguments.getString(KEY_VIDEO_ID);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(),
        //        "onInitializationSuccess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        thumbnailLoader = youTubeThumbnailLoader;
        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailListener());
        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(currentVideoID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
        String errorMessage =
                String.format("onInitializationFailure (%1$s)",
                        youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_youtube_thumbnail, container, false);
        ImageView playImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.playImageView);
        thumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView)view.findViewById(R.id.trailer_thumbnail);

        thumbnailView.initialize(getString(R.string.youtube_api_key), this);


        thumbnailView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StartVideo();
            }
        });
        playImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StartVideo();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        thumbnailLoader.release();

    }

    private void StartVideo(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),YoutubeVideo.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_VIDEO_ID, currentVideoID);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        thumbnailView = null;
        thumbnailLoader = null;
    }

    private final class ThumbnailListener implements
            YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail, String videoId) {
            //Toast.makeText(getContext(),
            //        "onThumbnailLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail,
                                     YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason reason) {
           // Toast.makeText(getContext(),
           //         "onThumbnailError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```